# Is it possible to set headers conditionally?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cache-control, mod-headers

I would like `.htaccess` to perform the following code ONLY if `http_referer` is from google (.com/ .ru/ .co.uk /.co.in/ etc.). Is this possible?

```
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well I figured out you can set headers a different way using mod_rewrite making it much easier:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google [NC]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [ENV=LONGCACHE:true]
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" env=LONGCACHE
Header set Pragma "no-cache" env=LONGCACHE
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT" env=LONGCACHE
```

Answer (score 12):

Note that you can put the condition in the Header command itself, in [ap_expr](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) format (does not require mod_rewrite):

```
Header set Pragma "no-cache" "expr=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}=~/(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider)/i && %{HTTP_REFERER}=~/google/i"
```

(not very useful in your particular case since you need to add 3 headers)

Comment: Mind you that the `expr` directive is only available in `apache-2.4.10` and later. Some server distributions, such as RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 run `apache-2.4.6` allthough they usually provide an optional higher apache version. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header